# Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions on Ubuntu Server 10.04

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install Guest Additions on my Ubuntu 10.04 VM running out of Virtual Box.  The problem starts when [the instructions](http://mylinuxramblings.wordpress.com/2010/06/03/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-ubuntu-server-10-04/) call for some menu feature that I cannot find, specifically:

> Go to the Virtualbox Devices entry on the menu bar of the guest OS and
>   select Install Guest Additions… , this will load the Guest Additions
>   ISO CD image.

I do not have any `Devices` entry on my menu bar on the guest window.

Comment: What is the host system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you have simply not noticed, this is what I see when running an Ubuntu guest on my Debian host:

[image]

The "Devices" menu should be on the VirtualBox window, not in the guest OS.

Comment: 10.04 does not come with a desktop environment, it is server only, i.e. only terminal.

Comment: on the VirtualBox menu I have VirtualBox, File, Machine, Window, and Help.  My host OS is Mac Mountain Lion

Comment: @amphibient that it is terminal based should make no difference since the relevant menu should be in VB's window, not part of Ubuntu. Are those the menus items you see when you have selected the Ubuntu window?

Comment: no, like i said, they are on the Virtual Box window

Comment: @amphibient OK, what do you see in the menu bar when the window that contains the VM is selected? At least on Linux, When I first run `virtualbox` I get a window showing me the installed VMs and when I launch one, it is launched in a new window. It is this second window that has the "Devices" menu.

Comment: OK, i found it now.

Comment: I installed the guest additions but my folder sharing still does not work.

Comment: @amphibient please post another question explaining what you've done, how you've set it up etc.

Comment: I think this one page helps out in your case. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp11306688

Comment: @amphibient I think Arpith's comment was directed at you.

Comment: never mind, i got it.  this was missing:  http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/access-virtualbox-shared-folder-from-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-guest-machine/